# Read Image from local network on MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How can i read an image from local network on razor page

For Example :

Image directory: 
\123.22.22.22\Image\xx.jpg

In razor page, when i put like that below, not working not reading img file.

```
<img src="\\123.22.22.22\Image\xx.jpg" >
```

Comment: Never use backslashes... you should use forward slashes instead. If it is not the same directory, to go one folder backwards, use `../` in front. If this is not the problem, I don't understand the question correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a local file, but you can create a virtual directory on the network or add the image to the project and access it by its relative path like:

`<img src="@Url.Content("~/Image/xx.jpg")" />`

Comment: Can you help me creating virtual directory

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory).